# Schema for a table in informix

Tags: database, informix

I have to design schema for a database table.

It goes like :

```
     field1 is TRUE/FALSE
     field2 is TRUE/FALSE
     field3 is TRUE/FALSE
     field4 is TRUE/FALSE
     field5 is char(50)  if field4 is TRUE
```

Can someone suggest an optimal schema for this kind of table.

I am using Informix database.

Comment: Which version of Informix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informix has a slightly peculiar BOOLEAN type.   You might prefer to use `fieldN CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(fieldN IN ('Y', 'N'))` (or `IN('T', 'F')`).  But BOOLEAN works within its limits.

```
CREATE TABLE Anonymous
(
    ID_Column     SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    field1        BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    field2        BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    field3        BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    field4        BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    field5        CHAR(50),
    CHECK((field4 = 't' AND field5 IS NOT NULL) OR (field4 = 'f' AND field5 IS NULL))
);
```

The values `'t'` and `'f'` are one of the peculiarities of Informix BOOLEAN; the names TRUE and FALSE aren't recognized.

Comment: Grumble: when I ran the SQL above, I got the error: `SQL -677: Check constraint cannot contain subqueries or procedures.` which does not make much sense.  There's no subquery in there; there's no explicit procedure invocation in there either.  I am not sure but I assume that there must be an implicit procedure call in the handling of `field4` in the constraint.

Comment: I think the OP's TRUE/FALSE datatype comes from MS-Access. Are Informix's BOOLEAN values case insensitive? I would prefer using INT or SMALLINT vs. CHAR(1) for TRUE/FALSE, as it consumes less storage and probably faster.

Comment: looks like the engine thinks CHECK is a function. Try removing one set of parenthesis.

Comment: The syntax is correct; it is the semantic interpretation that is dubious.  Change the type from BOOLEAN to CHAR(1) and the constraint is OK.  It's a weird bug in IDS (verified 11.70.FC6 on Mac OS X 10.7.5).

Comment: hmm, you discovered an additional BOOLEAN limitation! Is BOOLEAN internally stored as 1 or 0? Will CHECK work with NUMERIC types like SMALLINT, INT?.. The OP still hasn't responded as to what the value would be if field4 = FALSE!

Comment: This works: `CREATE TABLE t(i INTEGER NOT NULL, s CHAR(12) NOT NULL, CHECK((i > 10 AND s IS NOT NULL) OR (i <= 10 AND s IS NULL))
);` and so does this: `CREATE TABLE Anonymous2(ID_Column SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, field1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL, field2 CHAR(1) NOT NULL, field3 CHAR(1) NOT NULL, field4 CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK(field4 IN ('t', 'f')), field5 CHAR(50), CHECK((field4 = 't' AND field5 IS NOT NULL) OR (field4 = 'f' AND field5 IS NULL))
);` They're basically isomorphic except for the type. I created a bug in CQ (internal bug tracking system) for it.

Comment: good!.. Question is: Why with BOOLEAN did error say constraint has subquery or procedure? Perhaps BOOLEAN is like an opaque or UDT? BOOLEAN, TRUE/FALSE datatypes are frequently used in other DB's, adding more to modifications if an app or data is being converted to Informix.

Comment: Because BOOLEAN is treated as an 'extended type' rather than a 'built-in' type by IDS, and you can't invoke UDRs in CHECK constraints, but the condition requires invocation of a UDR, and ...  Suffice to say, it is a 'slightly peculiar' type; I'd probably stick with 'CHAR(1)' instead.  There's a lot of complex history dating back to about 1995 when Informix took over Illustra and integrated Illustra into Informix to create IUS (Informix Universal Server).

Answer (score 1):

What is field5 supposed to be if field4 is FALSE? A column's datatype cannot be conditional or dynamic! However, the size can be variable if you define a VARCHAR instead of a CHAR. What you can do is add an additional column for if field4 is FALSE.

```
field1 BOOLEAN,
field2 BOOLEAN,
field3 BOOLEAN,
field4 BOOLEAN,
field5 CHAR(50),  {if field4 is TRUE}
field6 DATATYPE   {if field4 is FALSE}
```

Comment: Chances are that `field5` should be NULL if the value in `field4` is `false`.

Comment: If that's the case then no need for field6, as field5's should can remain CHAR(50) and its value can be set to NULL, but the OP did not specify what the value should be if field4 is FALSE.